# There is no active transaction, How to workaround?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

**Context**

There is a custom plugin (CodeActivity) which called from javasript.
The C# code in the codeactivity calls multiple UpsertRequests and DeleteRequests on different custom technical entities. Neither operation triggers additional workflows.

The UpsertRequests may cause errors, for example when referencing not existing rows in other entities. Originally I thought I can catch those exceptions, then continue to process with the remaining items. However I can not catch this exception, instead it seems the codeactivity unconditionally terminated and the UI displays the following error message:

> There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom
>   plug-ins the ignore errors from service calls and continue processing

**Question**

**Q1:** Is my diagnostic statement correct about 
*"I can not catch this exception, instead it seems the codeactivity unconditionally terminated and the UI displays the following error message..."*

**Q2:**
What is the workaround for this? The original task is upsert multiple rows in a foreach cycle in a custom plug-in. If one row fails, then catch and continue to the next.

Comment: Suggest you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Does the code activity have [Enable rollback](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531121.aspx) set to true? If so I wonder if that is causing your issue as the purpose is to run your action in a transaction so that the operation, in it's entirety, can be committed or rolled back. In your case it sounds like you would want your action running outside of a transaction.